# Replace selected text inside p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I am trying to replace the selected text in the p tag.I have handled the new line case but for some reason the selected text is still not replaced.This is the html code.

```
 <p id="1-pagedata">
(d) 3 sdsdsd random:  Subject to the classes of this random retxxt wee than   dfdf month day hello the tyuo dsds in twenty, the itol ghot qwerty ttqqo   
</p>
```

This is the javascript code.

```
 function SelectText() {
 var val = window.getSelection().toString();
 alert(val);
$('#' + "1-pagedata").html($('#' + "1-pagedata").text().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,""));
$('#' + "1-pagedata").html($('#' + "1-pagedata").text().replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/gmi, ""));
$('#' + "1-pagedata").html($('#' + "1-pagedata").text().replace(val,"textbefore" + val + "textAfter"));
}

$(function() {
   $('#hello').click(function() {
      SelectText();
   });
});
```

I have also created a jsfiddle of the code.
https://jsfiddle.net/zeeshidar/w50rwasm/
Any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BGKSN/24/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do `$("#1-pagedata").html('New text here');`

Comment: actually i want to replace a part of  the text that the user selects so replacing is a must

Answer (score 0):

Since your `p` doesn't content HTML but just plain text, your can use both [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) as getter and setter.

Also, thanks to jQuery Chaining you can do all your replacements in one statement. So, assuming your RegExp's and replacement values are correct, try:

```
var $p = $('#1-pagedata');
$p.text($p.text().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,"").replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/gmi, "").replace(val,"textbefore" + val + "textAfter"));
```